# Is it possible to find if a new topic is created in activemq

Tags: activemq-classic

I am developing a system which, if someone creates a topic in ActiveMQ, is required to detect the new creation of a topic by a user logging in and create a Java instance which will subscribe to that topic to talk to the user.

What is the best way?

I know there is DestinationSource by which I can iterate over the currently generated topics or queues so that

I can find if a given topic is new or not.

Is this iteration over topic list is the best way to see if there are the new topic generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just subscribe to: `ActiveMQ.Advisory.Topic`

Then you get a datastructure [DestinationInfo](http://activemq.apache.org/maven/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/command/DestinationInfo.html) each time a topic is created or deleted.

Comment: Thanks for the link Tim.